# Why does the Microsoft Bing Translator not appear on website

Tags: bing-translator-api

I am attempting to use the  the bing translator on a site I am working on but I am not able to get it to display on the page. I have tried do what is suggested on the following site: https://www.bing.com/webmaster/tools/translator/

The following code has been applied to a navigation script as so

```
<header>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 pull-right collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
  <div class="navbar-form navbar-right form-inline hidden-xs hidden-sm">
    <div id='MicrosoftTranslatorWidget' class='Dark' style='color:white;background-color:#555555'></div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
setTimeout(function(){{var s=document.createElement('script');s.type='text/javascript';s.charset='UTF-8';s.src=((location && location.href && location.href.indexOf('https') == 0)?'https://ssl.microsofttranslator.com':'http://www.microsofttranslator.com')+'/ajax/v3/WidgetV3.ashx?siteData=ueOIGRSKkd965FeEGM5JtQ**&ctf=False&ui=true&settings=Manual&from=';var p=document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]||document.documentElement;p.insertBefore(s,p.firstChild); }},0);
</script>
</header>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Comment: @AlonEitan: Thank you for the suggestion. Question updated

Answer (score 0):

As [MS translator blog](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/blog/2019/06/27/the-translator-web-widget-will-be-retired-soon/) said, The Translator Web Widget will be **retired on July 31, 2019**. Beginning July 31st, the widget will no longer translate your webpages.

That could be a reason why your code doe4sn't work...